# It seems CSS and some errors are being saved to users accounts - session perhaps?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

So I have a pretty intricate site (in terms of Wordpress) running on Woocommerce. A customer wrote a complaint today that I had assumed was just a cache issue or something similar - turns out I was wrong.

Upon logging into the account, I am also met with the same issues. It is as though the issues are saved and limited to her account somehow, and not stored in her browser. I am assuming this is a session issue?

On the homepage the user appears logged out (the login button and register now links are still there - despite them being hidden if user is logged in). This is not the case when I access the site via one of several test accounts. Also, some of the CSS looks as though it isn't being loaded or is old.

When on the shop page the user is met with 2 notifications stating "The minimum spend for this coupon is $49.00." despite there being no coupons added, and also despite having more than $49.00 worth of product in the cart.

What type of thing could create user-specific issues that only occur depending on the account? How can I "flush" this so to speak? It is as though this stuff is being saved to the user?

Only thing I can think of is Session issues? Which I start with:

```
// -----------------------------------------
// START SESSION TO CREATE TEMPORARY VARIABLES

if ( !session_id() && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    session_start();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong there? Has anyone experienced something like this? I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Debug backtrace from where information is coming. Maybe something is loaded via WP page/plugin?

Comment: why do you *assume* this is a session issue?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Not sure... Sessions are a big weak area for me so I assume perhaps that is where I'm making errors.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't use sessions, it uses cookies instead, so it can't be sessions...unless you have added that feature yourself. The backtrace suggested is your best bet.